# Why "_db" variable is showing undefined?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to connect to mongodb. I have just started web development.

Here is my database.js code:

```
const mongodb= require('mongodb');

const MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

let _db;

const mongoConnect= callback=>{
    MongoClient.connect('mongodb+srv://pawan:*************@cluster0.vchvo.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority')
    .then(client=>{
        console.log('connected');
        _db= client.db();
        callback();
    })
    .catch(err=>{
        console.log(err);
        throw err;
    })
}

const getDb=()=>{
    if(_db){
        return _db;
    }
    throw 'no database found';
};

exports.mongoConnect= mongoConnect;
exports.getDb= getDb;
```

(I have changed password to  ******** only for the question)

Here is the Product.js(model) code

```
const mongodb = require('mongodb');

const getDb = require('../Util/database').getDb;

class Product {
    constructor(title, price, description) {
        this.title = title;
        this.price = price;
        this.description = description;
    }

    save() {
        const db = getDb();
    
        return db.collection('products')
            .insertOne(this)
            .then(result=>{
                console.log(result);
            })
            .catch(err=>{
                console.log("error from save in model"+ err);
            })
    }

}

module.exports= Product;
```

Upon running my node application I am able to view "connected" on my console. When after the line `_db= client.db();` I do `console.log(_db)` I get result as `[Object Object]`
but when I call `_db` in the `save() method of product.js model to establish connection` I get its value as `undefined` due to which I get the final result as `no database found`

Please guide me so that I could find out what I am missing?

Comment: Can you show `product.js` code as well? .

Comment: @SilvanBregy I have put the product.js code , please view it

Comment: I need the code in which you execute `mongoConnect` and  want to see if you call everythiung in correct order. Basically this code should work .

Comment: @SilvanBregy if you could provide your email id  i will be able to share the full code to you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears, that a small typo is the problem. You have to change a `require` statement in the `app.js`. Change this:

```
const mongoConnect = require('./util/database').mongoConnect;
```

to

```
const mongoConnect = require('./Util/database').mongoConnect;
```

Do you see the uppercase `U`?

#### Explanation

When importing `./util/database` and `./Util/database` (note the uppercase `U`) then `node` treats these files as different because the path is not exactly the same. Windows does actually point to the exact same file, but the `nodejs` cache treats them as different files why the file gets executed twice and your `_db` variable is actually newly declared in the second call.

This is a very confusing problem which only happens on windows.. Linux for example would treat these paths as differently! .

#### Showcase

Here's an example what shows the problem exactly.

**`value.js`**

```js
var value = 'NOT SET'
function setContent(_value) {
  value = _value
}

function getContent() {
  return value
}


exports.setContent = setContent
exports.getContent = getContent
```

**And `index.js`**

```js
var  { setContent } = require('./value')

setContent('New Value')

// import from same file, using the exact same path as setCOntent
var lowerCase = require('./value').getContent

// Note the uppercase "V" within the require.
var upperCase = require('./Value').getContent

console.log('LowerCase Import value (correct import.):', lowerCase())
console.log('UpperCase Import value (false import.):', upperCase())
```

**output**

```
LowerCase Import value (correct import.): New Value
UpperCase Import value (false import.): NOT SET
```

As you can see, the same file will be executed twice for different file paths. Maybe someone can try on linux? If it is the same behaviour?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying!